# If statement being skipped

Tags: c

In this method I am looking to see if a string appears in word search. Since a string can appear in any direction I have methods like the following which check those directions:

Currently my code is giving a segmentation fault when run. This is happening because the first if statement in my method is being skipped according to gdb.

The grid I am working with looks like this:

```
a r e o 
o n l y
o d d a
```

The values of x, y and str at runtime (just before segfault) are:

```
x = 0;
y = 0;
str = "add"
```

Now strlen(str) evaluates to 3 and `x - 3` evaluates to -3.

`-3 < 0` would evaluate true and quits my method. Unfortunately the if statement at the start of the method is skipped at run time. Anyone know what is going on?

Furthermore I'll add that if I change the first line of my grid to:

```
q r e o
```

I get proper results.

Here is the method:

```
bool checkNorth (int x, int y, string str) {
  //Deal with trival case and avoid array out of bounds/checking silly things
  if (x-strlen(str) < 0){
    return false;
  }
  //for each character in str 
  for (int i = 0; i < (strlen(str)); i++){
    //If the character above in the grid is the next character in the string
    if (grid[x-i][y].letter == str[i]){
      //keep going
      continue;
    }else{
      //It ain't north
      return false;
    }
  }
  //It's north
  return true;
}
```

Comment: why are you doing `strlen(str)`??? use `str.length()` (That's ***std::string***, right?)

Comment: @Amit: In C?  What are you thinking of?

Comment: @Amit This is C code, so I'll bet that `string` is really a `typedef` of `char*`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, PCLuddite, if that's a *typedef*, should be mentioned.

Comment: The tag says what the language is.  There's probably a header that's not shown, `#include <cs50.h>`, which would give the game away. It defines `typedef char *string;`.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the *if* statement is skipped': is it NOT executed, or it IS executed but the conditional expression results in `false`? In the latter case why don't you calculate `int cond = x - strlen(str);` to verify with gdb what the result is?

Comment: I have 7 other methods like the one above checking all varieties of cardinal directions (and their combos) with your solution id have to make sure to flip that '<' depending on which direction I'm checking in my loops correct? Since the solution works by ensuring that no str would go into negative space in the loop later on by ensuring we have a sufficiently large x in this case. Am I getting that right?

Comment: IMO: cs50.h and its definitions should never be used as a crutch to avoid learning the C language.  (in this case 'string' is actually `char *` so the code should use `char *`,  especially since 'string' does not enforce their being a NUL byte at the end of the char array

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings: (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` ) then the compiler would have told you: 1) that this line: `if (x-strlen(str) < 0){` always evaluates to false because a unsigned variable can never be less than 0.  2) this line: `for (int i = 0; i < (strlen(str)); i++){` is comparing signed to unsigned (because strlen() returns a size_t, not an int) 3) this line: `if (grid[x-i][y].letter == str[i]){` raises an error because 'grid' is not defined anywhere in the posted code.

Comment: when asking about a runtime problem, the posted code must cleanly compile.  The posted code has LOTs of problems including the required #includes are not posted.   Do you expect us to guess as to which header files you are using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since `strlen()` returns a value of type `size_t`, which is unsigned, then you compute `x - 3` the computation is done on unsigned values, and with unsigned arithmetic, `0 - 3` is a large positive value, and is never less than zero. In fact, since the comparison is for an unsigned quantity less than 0, but unsigned quantities can never be negative, the compiler can optimize the entire `if` test and the following `return` completely away.

You can fix the problem by changing:

```
if (x-strlen(str) < 0){
```

to:

```
if (x < strlen(str)) {
```

Note that your loop is somewhat inefficient.  You have:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (strlen(str)); i++){
```

This recomputes `strlen(str)` on each iteration.  You could write:

```
size_t len = strlen(str);

for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
```

This guarantees that the length is only computed once, which is sufficient unless you're modifying the string somewhere in the function, or one of the functions it calls.

Comment: `for (size_t i = 0; str[i]; i++) {` should be even better.

Comment: @mch: Yes, minor variants on that would work too (though the initial length check requires `strlen()` anyway).  Performance probably isn't a major problem even with the loops as written in the original.  The string sizes are small enough that it is not going to be a major problem repeating the `strlen()`.  If the strings were going to be multiple kilobytes or bigger, then it would add a measurable cost — unless the compiler is smart enough to be able to optimize the `strlen()` out of the loop condition.  I wouldn't rely on that being possible, but neither would I rule it out.